# How does collisions caculates when developing game in Build an HTML5 Game book

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't understand author's logic when calculating collisions between two circles (bubbles). Here is the [Calculating collisions](https://books.google.ru/books?id=MPxvCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA60&lpg=PA60&dq=px%20%3D%20ex%20%2B%20tdx&source=bl&ots=oZs5Wf7bJF&sig=0fKbOxG2aQGih_efFieKn8b7Ehs&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=W4ybVf-EEIOgsgH986RQ&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=px%20%3D%20ex%20%2B%20tdx&f=false) section.

Author writes:

> The bubble being fired follows a set of coordinates defined by the
>   equations:
>
> $$
> p_x = e_x + t\,d_x \\
> p_y = e_y + t\,d_y
> $$
>
> where px and py are points on the trajectory of the bubble’s center
>   point. The calculation of px and py happens in jQuery’s animate method
>   and is the standard equation for moving a point along a line. Next,
>   we’ll calculate t at the closest point on this line to the center of
>   the bubble that we’re checking against:
>
> var t = dx * distToBubble.x + dy * distToBubble.y;

I don't understand what `t` is  and why it calculates by the following formula:

`var t = dx * distToBubble.x + dy * distToBubble.y;`?

Comment: The text is a bit odd, $p_x$ and $p_y$ would usually be used for the coordinates of a point $p$, the text says they are two points. A distance is usually a scalar, but the code is about a vector. The work here would be to collect all definitions and then try to analyze what is going on.

Comment: I don't understand your answer, do you mean that book's explanations are wrong?

Comment: My comment meant that the book is unconventional (does things a bit different than most would do), so that your short excerpt is not enough for me to find out what is going on. I would need to read more of the text, what i might do later today when i have time to do this.

Comment: Also asked at [Math Overflow](http://mathoverflow.net/q/211059/12357).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vector $d$ was defined as $d_x = \sin \alpha, d_y = -\cos \alpha$ for some angle $\alpha$. This is a vector with length $1$ so it is a unit vector.

dist seems to be the difference vector between the centers of the two bubbles which are checked for collision.

Then $t$ is the scalar product between both of those vectors:
\begin{align}
t 
&= d \cdot \mbox{dist} \\ 
&= d_x \, \mbox{dist}_x + d_y \, \mbox{dist}_y \\
&= \lVert d \rVert \, \lVert \mbox{dist} \rVert \cos \angle(d, \mbox{dist}) \\
&= \lVert \mbox{dist} \rVert \cos \angle(d, \mbox{dist}) \\
\end{align}
which geometrically is the part of the vector dist projected in direction of the vector $d$.

[image: collision hitbox with moving center]

The image illustrates that $t$ (length of red vector $t\,d$) gives the distance between the center of the sphere moving in $d$ direction to where it comes closest to the other center on its flight path (trajectory). The trajectory is part of the line 
$$
s\,d \quad (s \in \mathbb{R})
$$

That closest distance is `distEC`. The point $t\,d$ is the midpoint of the intersection segment between hitbox and trajectory. The moving bubble enters the hitbox at $(t - dt)\, d$ and leaves at $(t + dt)\, d$.

The half-length of the intersection segment $dt$ is found with Pythagoras:
$$
dt = \sqrt{(2R)^2 - \mbox{distEC}^2}
$$

Comment: Thank you very mush for the response. You wrote that `The vector d was defined as dx=sinα,dy=−cosα for some angle α`. Coul you explain why vector `d` defined so?

Comment: It is just a means to specify a direction. That vector $d$ lies on a unit circle, for $\alpha = 0$ it points to $(0,-1)$ which is probably upwards, because the $y$ coordinates in the browser grow downwards. And for $\alpha = \pi/2$ it points to $(1, 0)$ which seems to the right etc.

Comment: but why vection `d` defines via `sin/cos`?

Comment: To translate an angle into a direction vector. See [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates).

Comment: Thanks for the best explanation!

Comment: could you explain one thing. Why we describe `dy=−cosα for some angle α` with minus?

Comment: The reason could be the coordinate system used by the web browser environment. DOM uses `left` and `top` properties. There $(\mbox{left}, \mbox{top}) = (0,0)$ is the left upper corner. So if you want to have the $d$ vector pointing upwards for the angle $\alpha = 0$, it should be $(0,-1)$, because decreasing `top` will move an object upwards.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25658/discussion-between-erik-and-mvw).

Comment: Sorry but one question. You wrote that `The vector d was defined as dx=sinα,dy=−cosα for some angle α` but according your link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates `x` defines via `cos` instead of `sin`

Comment: The wikipedia version is the common definition. Where the $y$ axis points upwards and $\alpha=0$ is to the right $d=(1,0)$. The book uses a different vesion, which is still a unit vector, the point  rotating on a unit circle, but more suited to the $y$ axis pointing downward and rotated by 90 degrees.

Comment: Thanks. I have the single incomprehension in book's author logic. How he calculates `offset1` and `offset2`. Which mathematical formula he used?

Comment: But why we get the intersection points as `(t±dt)d` ?

Comment: I updated the image.

Comment: Wow. Thanks you very much. It's the best explanation that I've ever seen on SO :)))